# Browser scrollbars problem with silverlight application.(Html)

Tags: html, css, silverlight

I have a simple silverlight application and i need to add the web browser scroll bars for it. (scroll bars not inside my silverlight app)

So I have html:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#silverlightControlHost {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:600px;
    min-width:800px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style><body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">       
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Infopulse.MobileOptimizer.xap"/>          
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />       
      <param name="culture" value="ru-ru" />
      <param name="uiculture" value="ru-ru" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
</body>
```

And i faced with next problem: 
 vertical scroll bar works not properly when scroll bar is enabled silverlight application not fits content of page. (Red arrow on screen shows the area without silverlight application) I dont now how to solve this problem.
Width fits normally. Inside silverlight application content set to stretch

Image:
[image: Problem with scroll bars]

I will be grateful for any information

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had the same problem in IE and Chrome and solved it using Javascript:

1. Add the following Javascript to your Silverlight test page.

   ```
   window.onload = resizeObject;
   window.onresize = resizeObject;
   function resizeObject() {
       var height = document.getElementById('silverlightControlHost').offsetHeight;
       document.getElementById('silverlightObject').height = height;
   }
   ```
2. Give your OBJECT tag the ID 'silverlightObject'.

   ```
   <object id="silverlightObject" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
   </object>
   ```
3. Test it.

Comment: A co-worker mentioned to me that we also had to resize the width to avoid getting horizontal scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting a overflow:auto; in div #silverlightControlHost style?
and remove the property from html,body

Comment: Ok, maybe I got the question wrong..What are you trying to achieve? do you want the div #silverlightControlHost to scroll according the the embedded object dimensions, is it?

Comment: height scroll cuts hulf of application. Application not fits to content when browser had vertical scroll.

Answer (score 1):

The `min-height` and `min-width` values in your `#silverlightControlHost` css look a suspiciously large when compared to your screen shot.

Have you tried changing their values (or removing them altogether) as a test to see if it affects the display?

If your `div` is larger than your browser window (which from your comment it appears to be) then that would explain the scroll bars. Make the minimum dimensions of the `div` smaller (if you can).

Comment: On the screen was taked when min size was 640x480. Without min values application looks perfect but without scroll bars... And width works normal (just white content page inside silverlight app)! With height i had problem

Comment: @Evgeny - that would explain it. Your div is larger than the screen size, hence the scroll bars.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I need scroll bars for my application but vertical scroll bar(height) crops silverlight application and i can scroll but application is cropped...

Comment: @Evgeny - I think I've missed the point of your question in that case.

Comment: I add some images to description, please take a look.

Comment: I need silverlight application to fitt content, and then if scroll appear to be scrolled to its borders. But vertical scroll can be scrolled much more that expected.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it using CSS only, by adding only these CSS line to my site:

```
body
{
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.silverlightControlHost
{
   height:100%;
}

html, body 
{ 
   height: 100% 
}
```

And of course assuming that the div holding the silverlight html object has the class assigned 'silverlightControlHost'